# Need help centering html elements using javascript

Tags: javascript

I need the JavaScript to align the footer and h1 to the center of the page, the function adjust should align the footer and h1 to the center of the page.

```js
function adjust(){
 document.querySelector("header h1").style.display = "center";
    document.querySelector("footer").style.display = "center";  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <main>
        <div>
           <h1>h1 text</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,consectetur adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis magni reprehenderit quibusdam ipsam eius odit iste consequatur necessitatibus voluptatibus deserunt maxime esse, similique, cupiditate facere quisquos iddelectus est.</p>
        </div>
        <div>
           <h2>Two</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem magni voluptatibus tempore aut corrupti, ducimus optio consequuntur. Quasi debitis a dicta natus voluptas alias ea, quis excepturi ut, eius accusantium.</p>
        </div>
    </main>
    <footer>
        <p>FOOTER</p>
    </footer>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The `display` css property doesn't control alignment, are you trying to center the text? or the elements themselves? (also, depending on your situation, I would suggest using CSS and simply adding or removing a class to your container element)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CSS property you are looking for is `text-align`, not `display`. It's `text-align: center;`.

Remember that hyphen-separated properties get camel-case property in JavaScript, so it becomes:

```js
document.querySelector("header h1").style.textAlign = "center";
```

Comment: Just a note, but when setting this prop on an element you refer to it using `textAlign`.

Answer (score 0):

simple use text-align: center..  if your problem still exist then use flexbox "display:flex;  justify-content: center; align "